# li is higher when it contains more content

Tags: html, css

I have a simple un-ordered list that is looking out of place.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        ....content
    </li>
    <li>
        ....content
    </li>
</ul>
```

Simple CSS styles

```
ul{padding-left:0;list-style:none;}
ul li{display:inline-block;}
```

I have more styles but there not really relevant to my problem.

This is an image of what my problem is:

[image]

As you can see, because the 3rd LI has two lines for the heading, it pushes the whole LI up.

Is there any way i can make these line up form the top and not the bottom?

Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yeah, you should build a demo